# key does not store in cache laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

here I'm trying to store key

```php
$code = mt_rand(111111, 999999);
Cache::put('notification', $code, 600);
```

and in another function I try to get that key in this way

```php
if(Cache::has('notification') and Cache::get('notification') == $request->code)
   return response()->json(['status' => true, 'group' => $request->res['group']]);
else
   return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'کد اشتباه است']);
```

but it always return false

Comment: what driver your using ?

Comment: on local ( file) , but on production (redis)

Comment: in local give witre permission if it is file

Comment: is it not working in redis or in local as well

Comment: no its not working , Cache::get('notification') always return null

Comment: does it have effect that (put) and (get) are in different function?

Comment: so in your local you are using memcached, so you can check for a random data & configuration, for Redis you can test if `Redis::get('notification')` gives you back data, also add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;` when using Redis class, for file you can check your file permissions for storage folder, which os you are using?

Comment: if you are using redis then you can also open redis in a terminal to check if key is there or not, use redis-cli, then check using `keys *`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be when you are using `Cache::get()` you are not storing the value anywhere. Please try to store it in a variable and compare the variable with `$request->code`.

```
$notification_cache = Cache::get('notification');
if (Cache::has('notification') and $notification_cache == $request->code)
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'group' => $request->res['group']]);
else
    return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'کد اشتباه است']);
```

Comment: and Cache::has('notification') always return false :)

Comment: Please check this section: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#checking-for-item-existence